# Merge list of arrays in map with duplicate keys in java

Tags: java-8, stream

I have multiple `numbers[]` arrays in the below request

I want to merge them into one map. If a key exists in multiple lists, in that case, I should merge arrays.

For example, the `Map` should be like:

```
{60075=[100,200,500,600], 60076=[700,600]}
```

Can someone help me with a way to complete my requirement?

### Request:

```
"details": [
        {
            "productSku": "60075",
            "numbers": [
                "100",
                "200"
            ]
        },
        {
            "productSku": "60075",
            "numbers": [
                "500",
                "600"
            ]
        },
        {
            "productSku": "60076",
            "numbers": [
                "700",
                "600"
            ]
        }
]
```

I tried the below code but it's not working:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map1 = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
for (Details details: detailsList) {
    List<String> numbers = (map1.get(details.getProductSku()));
    map1.put(details.getProductSku(), (numbers== null) ? numbers
            : numbers.addAll(diohShippingDetails.getSerialNumbers()));
}
```

Comment: Please share your attempts

Comment: @ETO i shared my attempts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your conditional `(numbers== null) ? numbers: numbers.addAll(diohShippingDetails.getSerialNumbers())` has two problems.

1. When numbers is `null`, which is the initial state as the map is empty, it uses `number` as result, which has been proven to be `null`, so the result would always be `null`.
2. [`addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)) does not return a list at all, but a `boolean`. You have to separate the expression to produce the map’s value from the `addAll` operation.

You can use something like

```java
List<String> numbers = map1.get(details.getProductSku());
if(numbers == null) {
    numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    map1.put(details.getProductSku(), numbers);
}
numbers.addAll(diohShippingDetails.getSerialNumbers());
```

When `map1.get(…)` returned a non-`null` `List`, we don’t need to put it again, but can add new elements to it. Only when `numbers` is `null`, we need to create a new list and put it into the map.

Alternatively, you can use

```java
Map<String, List<String>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
for(Details details: detailsList) {
    map1.computeIfAbsent(details.getProductSku(), key -> new ArrayList<>())
        .addAll(diohShippingDetails.getSerialNumbers());
}
```

`computeIfAbsent` will use the specified function (`key -> new ArrayList<>()`) to create and store a new value if none exists. It will return an already existing list or the list just created and stored. Therefore, you can unconditionally add the elements to the returned list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = 
    details.stream()
           .collect(
               toMap(Details::productSku, 
                     d -> d.getNumbers() == null ? Collections.emptyList() : d.getNumbers(), 
                     (a, b) -> Stream.concat(a.stream(), b.stream()).collect(toList())
               )
           );
```